# ¿Como bloquear el menu del navegador para mi aplicacion php?

Tags: javascript

tengo un sistema que hice con php, y obviamente se abre con el navegador,quisiera saber como bloquear esas opciones del navegador para que se vea como una aplicación de escritorio,creo que se puede hacer insertando un javascript en el index pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes un codigo en **PHP** que puedes usar para saber con que dispositivo se esta viendo tu pagina, la idea seria:

A) En el bloque que corresponde al dispositivo poner el codigo de la pagina que sera cargado;

B) Usar la variable `$tablet_browser` o `$mobile_browser` para asignar cuales bloques de codigo seran mostrados en la pagina deacuerdo al valor obtenido por esas variables.

Adjunto el codigo:

```
<?php

$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;
$body_class = 'desktop';

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $tablet_browser++;
    $body_class = "tablet";
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    $body_class = "mobile";
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    $body_class = "mobile";
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
      $tablet_browser++;
    }
}
if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
// Si es tablet has lo que necesites
   print 'es tablet';
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
// Si es dispositivo mobil has lo que necesites
   print 'es un mobil';
}
else {
// Si es ordenador de escritorio has lo que necesites
   print 'es un ordenador de escritorio';
}  
?>
```

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda...